# Ecukes step to set a variable

Tags: variables, ecukes

I have a package that changes its behavior based on several custom variables, and I want to set up scenarios based on those settings. Here is a step I wrote, but it doesn't seem to have any effect:

```
(When "^I set variable '\\([^\']+\\) to \"\\([^\"]+\\)\"$"
  (lambda (var val)
    (set (intern var) (eval (read val)))))
```

And I try to use it in a feature with:

```
Background:
  Given I switch to buffer "*package-test*"
  And I clear the buffer
  And I set variable 'package-enable-hash to "nil"
```

This doesn't seem to work, so what is the correct way to do this with ecukes?

Or maybe I have a scope problem so that the setting is not seen when a feature is run?

Comment: Specify what "doesn't seem to work" means.

Comment: The package behaves as if the variable were not set.  Hard to debug since its deep inside an ecukes session.

Comment: I was hoping that there was a best-practices ecukes way to do this, as it seems it would be a rather common setup for a scenario.

Comment: I don't know anything about `ecukes` (or `cucumber` for that matter) but I just wanted to suggest that you might want to open an issue at the `ecukes` site: it seems to be a very specific problem and you might find more experts at that site than you might here. And if you find an answer, you might want to provide a summary here as an answer to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`C-h f add-variable-watcher`:

> `add-variable-watcher` is a built-in function in ‘C source code’.
>
> `(add-variable-watcher SYMBOL WATCH-FUNCTION)`
>
> Cause `WATCH-FUNCTION` to be called when `SYMBOL` is about to be set.
>
> It will be called with 4 arguments: `(SYMBOL NEWVAL OPERATION WHERE)`.
>
> `SYMBOL` is the variable being changed.
> `NEWVAL` is the value it will be changed to.  (The variable still has
> the old value when WATCH-FUNCTION is called.)
>
> `OPERATION` is a symbol representing the kind of change, one of: `set`,
> `let`, `unlet`, `makunbound`, and `defvaralias`.
>
> `WHERE` is a buffer if the buffer-local value of the variable is being
> changed, `nil` otherwise.
>
> All writes to aliases of `SYMBOL` will call `WATCH-FUNCTION` too.
>
> Probably introduced at or before Emacs version 26.1.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion: I tried adding a logger to /dev/tty using 'add-variable-watcher and got no output.

Comment: Since this gives me a way to see what's going on in my code, I'm marking this the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that espuds already has such a step defined, which is almost identical to mine, so I am just going to use it for now and assume something else is going on.